# My turtle is acting weirdly. I am worried he could be dying

Tags: turtles

My turtle occasionally swims around his tank and splashes water everywhere. He flaps his flippers and makes a strange, crooning noise. It looks like he is spasmodic. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turtles get stir crazy and want to go around exploring and looking for other turtles. There is no solution, other than getting bigger tanks and adding more turtles.